# What is the best temperature to roast a spatchcock chicken?

Tags: chicken, temperature, roast

From your own personal experience, what was the best temperature and time it took to roast a whole chicken in the oven? Im doing a spatchcock. I want to know what temperature worked best for you to obtain the best result.

Thanks!

Comment: There are any number of sites dealing with roasting a spatchcock (if you're referring to a butterflied chicken). Serious Eats explains the science behind it best at http://www.seriouseats.com/2010/05/how-to-roast-a-chicken-butterflied-tips.html

Comment: hotter than you'd cook a trussed turkey -- it cooks faster, and you want to make sure it's hot enough to crisp up the skin.  Exact temp depends on how large of a bird it is (and if your oven's thermostat is accurate)

Comment: Yes, very hot! In Serious Eats, high oven temperature is talked about and they say 450-500° F is recommended.

Comment: Also, knowing what temp your oven is should help. My oven goes way beyond 450 if I set it for 450, for example. As for time, measure the temperature of the bird instead.

Comment: I love the info at Serious Eats, but I made my first spatchcocked chicken at 450 F, and got a lot of smoke and spattering grease - had to clean the oven after.  I wish I had put a broiler pan under there.  I use 425 F now and get fine results.

Answer (score 3):

I use a fairly high heat of 500F (260C) to render fat and crisp skin (after chicken has been air drying in the refrigerator overnight). Most of the time, for me, a whole chicken takes about an hour and 15 minutes.  Depending on size, a spatchcocked bird will take about an hour.  Use a thermometer to gauge your preferred doneness.

Answer (score 0):

I just roasted a spatchcock chicken from Trader Joe's at 425F for 1 hour and 15 minutes on the middle rack.

The marinade in the chicken package (which you do not rinse), and basting several times, helped with browning.  A convection oven would probably help as well.

Answer (score -1):

Cook in the centre of a 200c oven for 75 mins uncovered and cover with foil and rest for 20 mins.